# run Ruby script from USB flash driver using protable IE?

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, watir

I have ruby script my script makes some tests on web application. I would like to run it directly from my USB flash driver. In addition i don't want to use the system IE in way to make the user independent from my application no need to install any additional plug-in in his Browser.

Comment: I dont know, what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is i want to use a portable IE instead of using system Browser. The raison is my script require the Httpwatch plug-in while executing. I want to install it in a portable IE and force my script to use it. That's make my application independent from the user

Comment: Is there such thing as portable IE?

Comment: Yes i found IETester  but i dontknow how to force Watir to use it any suggestion will be very appreciated thanks.                        Here the link where you can find IE portable                     http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: That sounds like feature request to me. Ask Watir developers: http://rubyforge.org/mailman/listinfo/wtr-development

Answer (score 0):

To run ruby from your USB, just install ruby in your USB and run from prompt: `H:\ruby\bin\ruby.exe your_script.rb`. Everything will work as usual, including gems. About a portable IE... I don't know anyone.

Comment: In fact i convert my script to exe file using Ocra so i can use it directly from my USB...But still use the system IE